# Content does not change value on innerhtml

Tags: javascript, html

I'm practising javascript, though having a hard time that why the following inner html doesn't change values.

Here is my code:

```
    <a href="#" onmousedown="bleep.play()">home</a>
    <button onclick="GenerateTitle(1)">Generate</button>
    <div id="div1">Default Content...</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
var bleep = new Audio();
bleep.src = "sound.mp3";


function GenerateTitle(num){
bleep.play();
var div1= document.getElementById("div1");
div1.innerHtml = "load content for";
}
```

Comment: It's [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML), not `innerHtml`. That should work...

Answer (score 2):

Actually its **innerHTML** and not innerHtml

Answer (score 0):

As the above answers mentioned it should be `innerHTML` Please see the code below. I have amended the code

```js
var bleep = new Audio();
bleep.src = "sound.mp3";


function GenerateTitle(num){
bleep.play();
var div1= document.getElementById("div1");
div1.innerHTML = "load content for";
}
```

```html
 <a href="#" onmousedown="bleep.play()">home</a>
    <button onclick="GenerateTitle(1)">Generate</button>
    <div id="div1">Default Content...</div>
```